# Get consecutive days with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table with three columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 ( Id INT
                  ,VisitDate DATE
                  ,Counter INT)
```

AND test data:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (1,'2019-01-01', 50)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2,'2019-01-02', 15)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (3,'2019-01-03', 7)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (4,'2019-01-04', 7)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (5,'2019-01-05', 18)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (6,'2019-01-06', 19)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (7,'2019-01-07', 11)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (8,'2019-01-08', 1)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (9,'2019-01-09', 19)
```

Need to find three and more consecutive days where Counter more or equal ten:

```
Id  VisitDate   Counter
5   2019-01-05  18
6   2019-01-06  19
7   2019-01-07  11
```

My `SELECT` statement is

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
    ,IIF(Counter > 10, 1,0) AS MoreThanTen
    FROM   #t1
), lag_lead_cte AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,LAG(MoreThanTen) OVER (ORDER BY VisitDate) AS LagShift
    ,(LAG(MoreThanTen) OVER (ORDER BY VisitDate) +  MoreThanTen ) AS LagMoreThanTen
    ,LEAD(MoreThanTen) OVER (ORDER BY VisitDate) AS LeadShift
    ,(LEAD(MoreThanTen) OVER (ORDER BY VisitDate) +  MoreThanTen ) AS LeadMoreThanTen
    FROM cte
)
 SELECT *
 FROM    lag_lead_cte
 WHERE   LagMoreThanTen = 2 OR LeadMoreThanTen = 2
```

But the result is not fully consistent

```
Id  VisitDate   Counter
1   2019-01-01  50
2   2019-01-02  15
5   2019-01-05  18
6   2019-01-06  19
7   2019-01-07  11
```

Comment: What database management ssytem are you using? Sql Server? MySQL?

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a gaps-and-islands problem.
Here is one way to do it.
I'm assuming SQL Server based on the T-SQL tag.

Run this query CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,CASE WHEN Counter>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MoreThanTen
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VisitDate) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN Counter>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY VisitDate) AS rn2
    FROM #t1
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,rn1-rn2 AS Diff
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MoreThanTen, rn1-rn2) AS GroupLength
    FROM CTE_rn
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,VisitDate
    ,Counter
FROM CTE_Groups
WHERE
    GroupLength >= 3
    AND Counter > 10
ORDER BY VisitDate
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+---------+
| ID | VisitDate  | Counter |
+----+------------+---------+
|  5 | 2019-01-05 |      18 |
|  6 | 2019-01-06 |      19 |
|  7 | 2019-01-07 |      11 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: But if I want set   `GroupLength >= 2` I have got extra lines:

`3 2019-01-03 7`

`4 2019-01-04 7`

Comment: @TomKev, I forgot to add one filter. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select Id, VisitDate, Counter from (
    select Id, VisitDate, Counter, count(*) over (partition by grp) cnt from (
        select *,
               -- here I used difference between row number and day to group consecutive days
               row_number() over (order by visitDate) - day(visitDate) grp
        from #t1 
        where  [Counter] > 10
    ) a 
) a where cnt >= 3 --where group count is greater or equal to three
```

Based on the comment that days does not need to be consecutive, just rows have to be consecutive, here is updated query, which uses similair technique:

```
select id, visitdate, counter from (
    select id, visitdate, counter, count(*) over (partition by grp) cnt from (
        select *, rn - row_number() over (order by visitDate) grp from (
            select *,
                   case when (Counter > 10) or (lag(Counter) over (order by visitDate) > 10 and Counter > 10) then 
                   row_number() over (order by visitdate) end rn
            from #t1
        ) a where rn is not null
    ) a
) a where cnt >= 3
```

Comment: It's works when VisitDate is coming every other day. But does not work if day gap is two or more. For example, `1,'2019-01-01', 50` `2,'2019-01-03', 15`

Comment: @TomKev You specified "consecutive days". If there's gap between days, they are not consecutive.

Comment: @TomKev Well, it's up to you how you would use, I gave you logic that can be appliead in SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be most simply handled by just looking at the sequences using `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select id, visitdate, counter
from (select t1.*,
             lag(counter, 2) over (order by visitdate) as counter_2p,
             lag(counter, 1) over (order by visitdate) as counter_1p,
             lead(counter, 1) over (order by visitdate) as counter_1l,
             lead(counter, 2) over (order by visitdate) as counter_2l
      from t1
     ) t1
where counter >= 10 and
      ((counter_2p >= 10 and counter_1p >= 10) or
       (counter_1p >= 10 and counter_1l >= 10) or
       (counter_1l >= 10 and counter_2l >= 10) 
      );
```

Comment: So, if he wanted to find groups longer than, say, 5 rows instead of 3, he'd have to add `lag(counter, 3)`, `lag(counter, 4)`, `lead(counter, 3)`, `lead(counter, 4)` to the `SELECT` part of the query and add more filters to the `WHERE` part as well, right?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . For this version of the query.  There is an alternative approach that doesn't have this limitation, but the OP is not asking about longer sequences.

Answer (score -1):

```
Cross apply also works for this Question

    with result as (
select 
t.Id as Id1,t.VisitDate as VisitDate1,t.Counter as Counter1
,tt.Id as Id2,tt.VisitDate as VisitDate2,tt.Counter as Counter2
from #t1 t cross join #t1 tt where DATEDIFF(Day,t.VisitDate,tt.visitDate)=1
and t.Counter>10 and tt.Counter>10
)
select Id1 as Id,VisitDate1 as VisitDate ,Counter1 as [Counter] from result 
union  
select Id2 as Id,VisitDate2 as VisitDate,Counter2 as [Counter] from result
```

Comment: result is not correct

Comment: however my initial answer was correct, I've just add CTE to it to exactly fit the answer

Comment: Your result has 5 rows. Correct result  is 3 rows